# display items with column name and value in a list

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am currently trying to construct an iReport where i need to create a table that is not columned vertically but horizontally and cannot figure how to adjust the columns to do so.  I have to create a nutrition panel, if you know of another way to make this im more than willing to adjust to do this.  I wanted to use a table because there are items that do not nessicarily show up in a specified report (the nutrients at the bottom) that need to be somewhat dynamic.
The formatting needs to have support to have 2 columns with the nutrient name and percentage held inside Has anyone done this before or found any templates to assist with this?  I do not need any assistance with the query or formatting the data other than the placement.

UPDATE: thank you alex for showing me how to format this data, apparently my query however doesn't work with the formatting, my example query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    item1 as item1
    item2 as item2
    item3 as item3
from my_table
where my_table.id = P{Id}
```

SO my appended question is how do i display all the items by using the "as itemX" name and display the values based on that so it would be like this

```
item1  valueofitem1
item2  valueofitem2
item3  valueofitem3
```

The way the database is constructed i dont have a way of pulling these names as fields in the current data structure and that would be way too much work to fix just for this report frame.
I have looked and cannot find a "column name" function that seems to work

Comment: Can you pose the image of a design you want?

Comment: Did you see this post: [JasperReports: How to show data in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19255809/876298)?

Comment: I did not see that before, thank you alex, is there a way you can also set it to read the values (as the database i have has values of 0 sometimes and i dont want to display them every time) so that it works conditionally? I found finding information on iReport to be very tricky to find as far as tutorials that explain different methods you can use to make things better.