# Divide report result into two columns

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to divide report results into two columns to get an output (using Jasper Studio):

`result row 1`     `result row 4`

`result row 2`      `result row 5`

`result row 3`

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255809/jasperreports-how-to-show-data-in-two-columns) I've set *Column Count* value as 2 and *Print Order* as *Horizontal*.
But in this case I get an output:

`result row 1`     `result row 2`

`result row 3`      `result row 4`

`result row 5`

When I set a *Print Order* to *Vertical*, I get:

`result row 1`

`result row 2`

`result row 3`

`result row 4`

`result row 5`

And only if I set small *Page height* I get required output. But number of rows is always different. So I can't hardcode that small page height. Is it possible to calculate it somehow?

So how to get required output?

Here is an simple jrxml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test2" columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="481b7288-0681-43c8-b039-9e95ef42c274">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (12)"/>
<queryString language="jsonql">
    <![CDATA[array]]>
</queryString>
<field name="result" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="result"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[result]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="29" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="2d1cbfb0-be49-4f6e-8cd2-1e641ae6e21b">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c95f114a-b4bc-439b-aff0-23268822dc5d"/>
            </reportElement>
            <text><![CDATA[result]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="29" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="e9e3c344-22bd-4614-9adf-8bbd7a69bf96">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c95f114a-b4bc-439b-aff0-23268822dc5d"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{result}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

JSON data adapter was used in this example.
Here is content of the data adapter json file:
{"array": [
{
"ind": 1,
"result": "row 1"
},
{
"ind": 2,
"result": "row 2"
},
{
"ind": 3,
"result": "row 3"
},
{
"ind": 4,
"result": "row 4"
},
{
"ind": 5,
"result": "row 5"
}
]
}

**UPD:** I've found the solution. I've divided report into 2 subreports: one subreport is the left column, other is right column. In those subreports I check `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` and compare it with `numberOfRecords/2` in `printWhenExpression` to devide results into two parts.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal jrxml which will reproduce this issue?

Comment: In your desired output you mentioned row4 should start in the second column, which means first 3 rows should print in vertical and then start in second column and this should happen for any number of columns? This assumption that group of 3 rows should be printed before going to next column is correct?

Comment: Yes, but there may be any number of rows. More then 5.

Comment: I understand how you want your report to work up to 6 records. But when there are more than 6 records, where will be the 7th record shown? In 1st column below record `result row 5` ?

Comment: When there are 7 record, first column will be 1,2,3,4 and second 5,6,7.

Comment: So you want balanced number of rows in each column?

Comment: I just want to divide results into 2 columns. I guess my 
description is obvious.

Comment: @kostepanych If that's what you want, you have already achieved that. When you say "But number of rows is always different". What's the problem with that? Is that because you want to balance columns as Nikhil asked?

Comment: I achieved wrong order of results: 1,3,5 in first column and 2,4 in second. But I need 1,2,3 and 4,5. If n - is number of rows, I want to have n/2 rows in each column in case n is even number. But in case n is odd number, first column should have one more result than second column.

Comment: @kostepanych, If you get the count of records in the dataset, there is a way to do it. Although it will only work on a single page. Would that be okay? If not, then only option I can see is that you sort your data in the way you want and then use the horizontal 2 column print option.

Comment: Yes, I have the count of records. How to do it? –

Comment: @kostepanych, I have added my sample `JRXML` of how to do it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how you can do it if you have count in dataset. Also note that it will only work if report ends in a single page -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.15.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.15.0-dd49bfb94918336b8321d5507193f0169ead4e95  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test2" columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="481b7288-0681-43c8-b039-9e95ef42c274">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SampleDB"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select result, count
from sampletable]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="result" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="result"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="result"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="sampletable"/>
    </field>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="count"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="count"/>
    </field>
    <group name="Group1" isStartNewColumn="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}%2 == 0 ? ($V{REPORT_COUNT}  <= $F{count}/2) : (($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) <= $F{count}/2)]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="29" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="2d1cbfb0-be49-4f6e-8cd2-1e641ae6e21b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c95f114a-b4bc-439b-aff0-23268822dc5d"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[result]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="29" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="e9e3c344-22bd-4614-9adf-8bbd7a69bf96">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="c95f114a-b4bc-439b-aff0-23268822dc5d"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{result}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Below are the changes  -

1. Add count to result (Here I am using database dataset with count in query, but you do any other as long as you can get total count to use in report) -

[image]

2. Now, edit report format to add 2 columns and keep the print order as vertical -

[image]

3. Then, create a group in the report with `group expression` as - `$F{count}%2 == 0 ? ($V{REPORT_COUNT}  <= $F{count}/2) : (($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) <= $F{count}/2)`, here `$F{count}` is the total record count from the dataset and `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` is the inbuilt variable to get the row number.

[image]

4. Finally, check `Start New Column` in the `Group Band Properties` -

[image]

This would divide rows equally into 2 columns as long it is a single page.

---

Alternatively, you can sort your records (it would be a very complex sort) and then set the report page format as 2 column and set print order to horizontal.

Comment: Unfortunately my report not always fit one page. So I've found the solution myself with 2 subreports. But thanks for trying to help!